# iPad modal view controller similar to Mail.app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad

How can I create a modal window in my iPad app similar to the one shown on Apple's website for composing messages in Mail.app?

Example:

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/413086/mail_type_20100225.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: The iPhone SDK version 3.2 (the iPad version) is still under NDA, so any answer to this may be against Apple's developer agreement. That said, don't expect a lot of responses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use a normal view controller, assign the `modalPresentationStyle` property, and present it as a modal view controller. Please read the "iPad Programming Guide" / "Views and View Controllers" for detail.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html

Comment: The `modalPresentationStyle` you are looking for by the way igul222, is `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

Comment: [Modal Presentation Style](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle) (UIViewController Class Ref)