# Segue to another view controller while keeping parent controller partially visible

Tags: iphone, swift3

I'm looking to segue into another controller while still partially showing the parent container. Similar to when you start a new email message from the iphone mail app (See screenshot below). I've searched but could not find an example or answer.

[For Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc1gD.png)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485015/ipad-modal-view-controller-similar-to-mail-app